# Unable to create KAA application using REST API :403 Error

Tags: rest, kaa

I am trying to create the Kaa application initial setup using all REST calls instead of using Kaa admin UI.I tried hitting API  : 
http://:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/application
As a Tenant Administrator (admin:admin123) in case of sandbox. 
I get error code 403: Forbidden. Do I need to change anything on configuration side?
See the screen-shot:

[image: 1]

Comment: Can we add new applications in kaa sandbox?

Comment: Yes @Pete I am able to create the applications is sandbox using admin UI. But REST call fails

Comment: Can you share the request body?